# On localization at a prime ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $(A,\mathfrak m)$ be a commutative ring with $\dim A=d$ and $\mathfrak p$ a prime ideal of $A$. If $(A/\mathfrak p)_{\mathfrak q}=0$ for all primes $\mathfrak q$ with $\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak q=d-1$, then $\mathfrak p=\mathfrak m$. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $(A/\mathfrak p)_{\mathfrak q}=0$ iff $\mathfrak p\not\subseteq\mathfrak q$. Then the question is the following:

> If $\mathfrak p$ is not contained in any height $d-1$ prime ideal of $A$, can we conclude $\mathfrak p=\mathfrak m$?

Well, in general, we can't. Let $A$ be a noetherian local domain of dimension three which is not catenary (Nagata's example), and $(0)\subset\mathfrak p\subset\mathfrak m$ a saturated chain. Then $\mathfrak p$ has height one and it is not contained in a height two ideal of $A$.